# Swift String Formatter that filters out commas

Tags: swift, string, formatter

Is there a `Formatter` in `Swift` that filters out commas (or some substring)?  It must use the `Formatter` protocol.  Something like this would be great:

```
static let myCommaFilter : Formatter = {
  // TextFormatter?
  StringFormatter(filter: { input in // (String)->String
    input.replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: "")
  })
}()
```

The `TextField` view in `SwiftUI` offers an initializer with a `Formatter` which I thought I could use to filter out commas out of user's input.

Comment: Do tell me what formatting is

Comment: No, there is no standard Formatter that filters text from text. Why does it need to be a Formatter? `String` already has methods for filtering text (as you use in your question's code).

Comment: Formatters generally take non-string data (dates, ints, floats, etc) and convert them to-from string representations. What you are asking about seems more like string parsing methods. Apple's docs on the Formatter class says: "An abstract class that declares an interface for objects that create, interpret, and validate the textual representation of values."

Comment: And it also says: "The Foundation framework provides several concrete subclasses of Formatter, including ByteCountFormatter, DateFormatter, DateComponentsFormatter, DateIntervalFormatter, MeasurementFormatter, NumberFormatter, and PersonNameComponentsFormatter"

Comment: @Duncan Excellent comments, much appreciated.  The `TextField` view in SwiftUI offers an initializer that accepts a formatter.  I need to filter out commas out of user input in the text field.  The alternative is to filter out the comma using an `.onChange(of: myTextFieldString)` view modifier, which would work.  Besides that, do you have any other solutions?

Comment: I haven't taken the plunge into SwiftUI yet, so I'm not a good one to answer that. I would suggest adding the SwiftUI tag to your question and rephrasing it to explain that you want to update the contents of your TextField on changes and filter out commas.

Comment: So you want to initialize the TextField with the formatter so that the TextField will automatically filter the commas out of the user input for you?

Answer (score 1):

you could try something simple like this alternative approach,

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var txt = "something"
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(txt)
            TextField("", text: Binding(
                get: { txt },
                set: { if !$0.contains(",") { txt = $0 }}
                // or alternatively
                // set: { txt = $0.replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: "")}
            )).border(.red)
        }
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create classes that inherit from `Formatter` and/or `FormatStyle`, `ParseableFormatStyle` to use the `format` variation for SwiftUI.

Here is a rough example

```
class CommaFormatter: Formatter {
    override func string(for obj: Any?) -> String? {
        guard let obj = obj as? String else{
            return nil
        }
        return obj.replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: "")
    }
    override func getObjectValue(_ obj: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<AnyObject?>?, for string: String, errorDescription error: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSString?>?) -> Bool {
        obj?.pointee = string.replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: "") as AnyObject
        return true
    }
    
    override func isPartialStringValid(_ partialString: String, newEditingString newString: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSString?>?, errorDescription error: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSString?>?) -> Bool {
        newString?.pointee = partialString.replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: "") as NSString

        return !partialString.contains(",")
    }
    
}
```

Then in SwiftUI you can use

```
TextField("", value: $string, formatter: CommaFormatter())
```

It will update the `string` when the user `submit`

Comment: Why not just a Swift native filter instead of Foundation method replacingOccurrences?

Comment: @LeoDabus filter? How would you use filter?

Comment: `string.filter { $0 != "," }`

Comment: @LeoDabus I didn’t even think about that, do you know how the 2 compare in terms of O?

Comment: [Which is more performant: replacingOccurrences or components(separatedBy:).joined()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56020219/2303865)

Comment: @LeoDabus Good info, without benchmarking I would expect them to be very similar. But regex based methods tend to be faster I believe. But the Vapor issue is very valid too.

Comment: Actually Foundation can be imported only UIKit can't when developing with Vapor