# Remove all the spaces from a string at the beginning or end - swift

Tags: ios, swift, string, whitespace

How can I remove all white space from the beginning and end of a string?

Like so:

`"Test User Image"` returns `"Test User Image"`

`"Test User Image   "` returns `"Test User Image"`

`" Test User Image   "` returns `"Test User Image"`

`" Test User Image   "` returns `"Test User Image"`

**Question:** How to remove all the white spaces from a string at the beginning or end?

Can someone please explain to me how to remove all the white spaces,  I've tried with the below answers but no results yet.

[How should I remove all the leading spaces from a string? - swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28570973/how-should-i-remove-all-the-leading-spaces-from-a-string-swift)

[How to remove all the spaces and \n\r in a String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34940044/how-to-remove-all-the-spaces-and-n-r-in-a-string)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add the code you have tried, the solutions in the linked questions works so it’s very unclear why it isn’t working for you

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
let str = "    Test    User    Image   "
str.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
```

> output:
> `"Test    User    Image"`

Comment: No, the output is `"Test    User    Image"`. `trim` does not remove spaces between two other characters. And if it did the output would be `"TestUserImage"`. But it answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

Please check it out,

```
let name = " I am Abhijit "
let trim = name.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
print(trim)
print(name.count)
print(trim.count)
```

I hope you got the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `name.trimmingCharacters(in:)` using the WhiteSpace character set as parameter, but this has a cost because it calls the underlying `NSString` function.

A pure Swift implementation may look as below:

```
extension String {

    func trimmedWS() -> String {
        guard let start = firstIndex(where: { !$0.isWhitespace }) else {
            return ""
        }
        let reversedPrefix = suffix(from: start).reversed()
        let end = reversedPrefix.firstIndex(where: { !$0.isWhitespace })!
        let trimmed = reversedPrefix.suffix(from: end).reversed()
        return String(trimmed)
    }

}
```

```
print(" Test User Image   ".trimmedWS())
```

Prints: "`Test User Image`"